# Give public access to a private npm module from a private github repo

Tags: github, npm, private

I have a private npm module registered for a private github repo.

I want to enable a client to install this npm module. I can "npm access" him to the module, so he is able to reach the module... However, he still can't access the github repo for getting the download...

How can I achieve this?

Edit:
to clarify, i can't add the client as collaborator to the github repo, because i can't let look into issues/PRs... sadly, github has no option for hiding issues/PRs for non-admins

Comment: Ionică Bizău, i appreciate the edit, however, i am **not** talking about collaborators!

Comment: I am trying to get an npm private repo setup on github. Do you have any guidance for me? Any instructions you can point me to?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access your private repository, you have to add your client as collaborator. To add him as collaborator in your GitHub repository, you have to go to the *Collaboration* settings:

> https://github.com/user/repo/settings/collaboration

(replace `user` with your username and `repo` with your repository name)

Note that `npm` supports installing packages from git too. So, your friend can do:

```
npm install user/repo
```

(obviously, after having access to the repository)

Comment: i edited the question to be more specific, i am not talking about collaborators

Comment: @chris Does the private module uses the repository as dependency? Or why isn't the `npm access` enough?

Comment: yes, i am not aware, that i can have a npm module not being downloaded from github on install?

Comment: @chris If you have a *private module on npm*, then you should `npm publish` the module there. And your client that has access should be able to install it, otherwise he needs rights in your git repo. You can also create a new repository (without any issues) and push the code there and give him rights. That would be an alternative.